# Reading nested json file with a class - Python

Tags: python, json, class, dictionary

I have a json file with the structure like the following

```html
{
   "field": {
     "output": {
       "Product": { "min": 26, "max": 80 },
       "Range": { "min": 0.01, "max": 0.04 }
     },
     "input": {
       "Powder": { "selected": true },
       "liquids": { "selected": true },
       "solids": { "selected": true }
     }
   }
```

I created a class to read the json elements like a dict or array:

```py
class ProductConfig(dict):
  def __init__(self. args):
    dict.__init__(self, args)

    feature_set_input = args.get('field', {})
    outputs = feature_set_input.get('output', [])
    inputs = feature_set_input.get('inputs', [])

    self.outputs = list(map(output.from_dict, outputs)) # Check if the get is working
    self.inputs = list(map(Input.from_dict, inputs)) # Check if the get is working
    

    def from_dict(values: dict):
     result = JobConfig(values)
     return result


 class Input:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id 

   def from_dict(values):
    return Input(values)

 class output:
    def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id 


   def from_dict(values):
    return output(values)
```

I want to have an array of values in an element like if:

```py
ProductConfig.outputs =  [id:Product, min:26, max:80]


ProductConfig.input = [id:Powder, selected:true]
```

What should I do to achieve that.

Thanks

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre]. I don't see anywhere in this code you reading a JSON file. Nor how you actually use these classes. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want to achieve, as your desired output doesn't show any specific type/data type. Besides, as mentioned by @buran, you are skipping important information, which makes it hard to follow your problem or replicate anything. I can only guess that you are looking for something like this:

```py
from itertools import chain


some_dict = {
    "field": {
        "output": {
            "Product": { "min": 26, "max": 80 },
            "Range": { "min": 0.01, "max": 0.04 }
        },
         "input": {
           "Powder": { "selected": True},
           "liquids": { "selected": True},
           "solids": { "selected": True}
         }
    }
}


class ProductConfig(dict):
    
    @staticmethod
    def _decompose(dictionary: dict) -> list:
        return [str(key) + ": " + str(dictionary[key]) for key in dictionary]
    
    @staticmethod
    def _flatter(ls: list) -> list:
        if type(ls) == list:
            for items in ls:
                for item in ProductConfig._flatter(items):
                    yield item
        else: yield ls
    
    def __init__(self, args):
        dict.__init__(self, args)

        feature_set_input = args.get('field', {})
        outputs = feature_set_input.get('output', [])
        inputs = feature_set_input.get('inputs', [])
        
        inputs = args["field"]["input"]        
        self.inputs = list(chain.from_iterable((f"id: {key}", ProductConfig._decompose(inputs[key])) for key in inputs))
        self.inputs = list(ProductConfig._flatter(self.inputs))
        
        inputs = args["field"]["output"]        
        self.outputs = list(chain.from_iterable((f"id: {key}", ProductConfig._decompose(outputs[key])) for key in outputs))
        self.outputs = list(ProductConfig._flatter(self.outputs))

        
processed_dict = ProductConfig(some_dict)   

print(processed_dict.inputs)
print(processed_dict.outputs)

---------------------------------------------------------------------
['id: Powder', 'selected: True', 'id: liquids', 'selected: True', 'id: solids', 'selected: True']
['id: Product', 'min: 26', 'max: 80', 'id: Range', 'min: 0.01', 'max: 0.04']
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```